# What does the Error Message in DSolve really mean?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Having this ordinary non linear differential equation

$$y'-x^2 (y+1)\cdot (y-2)^2= 0$$
with the boundary condition $y(4)=2$. When trying to solve this one with Mathematica by using

```
DSolve[{y'[x] - x^2 (y[x] + 1) (y[x] - 2)^2 == 0, y[4] == 2}, y[x], x]
```

it gives an empty set of solution and returns

```
DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution. >>
```

As we have 
$$y'=x^2(y+1)\cdot (y-2)^2$$ 
which is clearly lipschitz continuous a local unique solution exists. In special 
$$y=2 \quad \forall x$$
is a solution of the differential equation. 
When using `NDSolve`and plotting the results it looks pretty much like the constant function which solves the ode. How does it come that Mathematica says there is no solution?

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1 (Student Edition).

Comment: I would just generalize the boundary condition to `y[a]==b`. And to obtain trivial ones use `Reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to find the general solution with initial condition `y[x0]==y0` you see what happens

```
sol = y[x] /. 
  First@DSolve[{y'[x] - x^2 (y[x] + 1) (y[x] - 2)^2 == 0, y[x0] == y0}, y[x], x]
```

[image]

As you see when `y0==2` is directly inserted into the solution the denominator becomes zero. At this point you could use `Limit` to investigate further.